# Horizontal date intervals to Vertical dates (possibly a sql/vba loop solution?)

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, date, intervals

Is there a quicker way to convert my data from columns a - d being personnel information, then column e being leave starting day and column f being leave ending day to the following:

Column a - d repeating on each row and column e being a seperate row for each day/date included in the range?

At the moment I am doing this manually to prepare large leave taken/clocked in recon.

I should also add that each row contains a interval for an employees leave taken and that same employee could appear more than once in the dataset.

I am reading up on SQL scripts although it doesn't appear to cover this case with so many rows and intervals to create for each person.

Comment: You can import the data to an invisible sheet en than display it in a second sheet, where you use formula's to point to the right data in the first sheet.

Comment: Please show table structures / scripts and example data. Also please show examples of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve this problem in SQL, then you can use a calendar or dates table for this sort of thing.

For only 152kb in memory, you can have 30 years of dates in a table with this:

```
/* dates table */
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
/* 30 years, 19 used data pages ~152kb in memory, ~264kb on disk */
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
    [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
into dbo.Dates
from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
               cross join n as tenK  cross join n as hundredK
order by [Date];
create unique clustered index ix_dbo_Dates_date on dbo.Dates([Date]);
```

Without taking the actual step of creating a table, you can generate an adhoc tables of dates using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with just this:

```
declare @fromdate date, @thrudate date;
select @fromdate = min(fromdate), @thrudate = max(thrudate) from dbo.leave;

;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
```

Use either like so:

```
/* `distinct` if there are overlaps or duplicates to remove */
select distinct 
    l.personid
  , d.[Date]
from dbo.leave l
  inner join dates d
    on d.date >= l.fromdate
   and d.date <= l.thrudate;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/AVOIN59493

from this test data:

```
create table leave (personid int, fromdate date, thrudate date)
insert into leave values
 (1,'20170101','20170107')
,(1,'20170104','20170106') -- overlapped 
,(1,'20170420','20170422') 
,(2,'20170207','20170207') -- single day 
,(2,'20170330','20170405')
```

returns:

```
+----------+------------+
| personid |    Date    |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | 2017-01-01 |
|        1 | 2017-01-02 |
|        1 | 2017-01-03 |
|        1 | 2017-01-04 |
|        1 | 2017-01-05 |
|        1 | 2017-01-06 |
|        1 | 2017-01-07 |
|        1 | 2017-04-20 |
|        1 | 2017-04-21 |
|        1 | 2017-04-22 |
|        2 | 2017-02-07 |
|        2 | 2017-03-30 |
|        2 | 2017-03-31 |
|        2 | 2017-04-01 |
|        2 | 2017-04-02 |
|        2 | 2017-04-03 |
|        2 | 2017-04-04 |
|        2 | 2017-04-05 |
+----------+------------+
```

---

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Guys how i solved this was actually just using another formula on this forum involving a join and between with the date intervals.

Worked fine!

Ps used the calendar for another scenario regarding actual work days taking into account weekends and public holidays....

Thanks